# How to select only columns (type=factor) with less than n levels with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a problem similar to this: I want to select just the columns with less than "n" levels, and I think I could do this using dplyr, but I don't know how.

Follows an example with Titanic data, where with `str()` I have 3 factors with 2 levels and 1 factor with 4 levels. My ideia is to select just the columns with less than 4 levels.

`str(as.data.frame(Titanic) %>% mutate_if(is.character, factor))`

Any ideia?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pass a function to `select_if`, much like `mutate_if` -- see `?nlevels`:

```
Titanic %>%
  as_data_frame() %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, factor) %>%
  select_if(~ nlevels(.) < 4)
```

Note that you could also write this as: `select_if(function(x) nlevels(x) < 4)`

Comment: Perfect!! I also added a `select_if(~ is.factor(.) == TRUE) ` between `%>%`, to be sure that I will not get numerical columns.

Comment: @WlademirRibeiroPrates yep, you can actually simplify that to just `select_if(is.factor)` or you could even use just one statement `select_if(~ is.factor(.) & nlevels(.) < 4)`

Comment: One can even write `select_if(~length(unique(.))<4)` which can work across all types.

Answer (score 1):

With the new dplyr verbs:

```
Titanic %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character),.fns = as.factor)) %>% 
  select(where(~nlevels(.)<4))
```